# Count the amount of times a word is repeated

Tags: c#, list, loops, count, nested-loops

I'm pretty new to C# however I am trying to solve this question down below. Any way I can count that specific word each time even when its repeated twice in the same list element? I am trying to not use the Split() function. Thanks for the help

```
string wordToSearch = "Pig";
List<string> sentences = new List<string>()
             {
                 "The animal I really dig,",
                 "Above all others is the pig.",
                 "Pigs are noble. Pigs are clever,",
                 "Pigs are courteous. However,",
                 "Now and then, to break this rule,",
                 "One meets a pig who is a fool.",
                 "What, for example, would you say,",
                 "If strolling through the woods one day,",
                 "Right there in front of you you saw",
                 "A pig who'd built his house of STRAW?",
                 "The Wolf who saw it licked his lips,",
                 "And said, 'That pig has had his chips.'",
                 "'Little pig, little pig, let me come in!'",
                 "'No, no, by the hairs on my chinny-chin-chin!'",
                 "'Then I'll huff and I'll puff and I'll blow your house in!'"
             };
foreach (string sentence in sentences)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (sentence.ToUpper().Contains(wordToSearch.ToUpper()))
    {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine(sentence + " " + "[" + count + "]");

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sentence + " " + "[" + count + "]");
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I am trying to not use the Split() function"* Why?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to call `IndexOf` in a loop, until there are no more matches found:

```
static int CountRepeats(
    string source,
    string toFind,
    StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    int result = 0;
    int index = source.IndexOf(toFind, comparison);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        result++;
        
        // Resume the search just after the end of the previous occurrence:
        index = source.IndexOf(toFind, index + toFind.Length, comparison);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

**NB:** As with your current code, this will find matches within other words. For example, it will find the `pig` in `spiggot`. That may or may not be correct, depending on the precise requirements.

If you want the *total* count across all sentences, you'll need to move your `count` variable outside of your loop:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string sentence in sentences)
{
    int sentenceCount = CountRepeats(sentence, wordToSearch);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}]", sentence, sentenceCount);
    count += sentenceCount;
}

Console.WriteLine("Total count: {0}", count);
```

Comment: What I need is for every line to indicate how many times the word pig is repeated. Even for pigs. For example I need the 3rd element of the list to indicate that the word pig was repeated twice.

Comment: Well that's good, because that's exactly what this code does.

Comment: [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EdUHH8)

Comment: Any possible way to do it with using the built in function of IndexOf? As I am trying to restrict myself from certain functions

Comment: That *is* using the built-in `IndexOf` function. There isn't a built-in function to find all indexes of the specified substring; you just need to use `IndexOf` in a loop, like I have here.

Comment: I understand. Its just that the problem I'm trying to solve restricts me from using certain inbuilt functions such as IndexOf. It actually requires me to use a nested loop.

Comment: So use `IndexOf` in a loop, as I did in the `CountRepeats` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (string sentence in sentences)
            {
                int count = 0;
                if (sentence.ToUpper().Contains(wordToSearch.ToUpper()))
                {
                    string[] words = sentence.ToUpper().Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
                    Console.WriteLine(sentence + " " + "[" + words.Where(s => s.Equals(wordToSearch.ToUpper())).Count().ToString() + "]");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sentence + " " + "[" + count + "]");
                }

            }
```

Comment: Can't use split and replace functions unfortunately

Comment: How about this; count  = Regex.Matches(sentence.ToUpper(), @"\b(PIG)\b").Count;
                    Console.WriteLine(sentence + " " + "[" + count.ToString() + "]");

Answer (score 0):

Try this using regex pattern match and get the count.

```
int iCount = 0;
string pattern = @"p(.*?)g";
foreach (string sval in sentences)
{
   foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sval, pattern))
   {
      if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 0)
      {
         iCount++;
      }
   }
}
```